# Sorting array of object based on range of Numbers of String

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

I have an array of object like

```
let myObj =[{
              "60+": 0.1413972485314015,
              "18-29": 0.0832178903621611,
              "40-49": 0.1033361204013377,
              "30-39": 0.0835906328864075,
              "Under 18": 0.1326368677036551,
              "50-59": 0.1224973366151133
           }]
```

I want to sort the above array of object like

```
let myObj =[{
             "Under 18": 0.1326368677036551,
              "18-29": 0.0832178903621611,
              "30-39": 0.0835906328864075,
              "40-49": 0.1033361204013377,
              "50-59": 0.1224973366151133
              "60+": 0.1413972485314015,
           }]
```

How can i achieve this kind of sorting using javascript ?

Comment: please add your try and what goes wrong.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: Is there only one object? If so why is that inside the array?

Comment: Have a look at Object.keys

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal , it is a part of a big object . I have just put only one for simplification.

Comment: @Atulkumarsingh that is totally incorrect way to ask a proper question. You should specify that.

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal, I really don't think that is necessary at all. And I also don't think there is anything wrong with the question. I have provided only the necessary information which i need. And be it even one object in the array , i need only that much.

Comment: @Atulkumarsingh it is still a "gimme teh codez" type question. Next time please post what you tried. You even have a comment _I was trying the same thing , but making mistake in the forEach section._ so seeing that code would have allowed us to fix your code too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use first character to sort and consider if first character is number it is small,

```js
let myObj = [{
    "60+": 0.1413972485314015,
    "18-29": 0.0832178903621611,
    "40-49": 0.1033361204013377,
    "30-39": 0.0835906328864075,
    "Under 18": 0.1326368677036551,
    "50-59": 0.1224973366151133
}];

const ordered = {};

Object.keys(myObj[0]).sort(
    function(a, b) {
        if (isNaN(Number(a.charAt(0))))
            return -1;
        if (isNaN(Number(b.charAt(0))))
            return 1;
        return a.charAt(0) - b.charAt(0);
    }

).forEach(function(key) {
    ordered[key] = myObj[0][key];
});
console.log(ordered);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I was trying the same thing , but making mistake in the forEach section. It is working perfectly.

Comment: Already done that.

Answer (score 2):

You could take an offset for `Under` and `+` quantifier and take the value, depending on the sorting position. Then return the delta of values or the delta of the offset.

Later, you could build a new object with sorted keys.

```js
var object = { "60+": 0.1413972485314015, "18-29": 0.0832178903621611, "40-49": 0.1033361204013377, "30-39": 0.0835906328864075, "Under 18": 0.1326368677036551, "50-59": 0.1224973366151133 },
    keys = Object
        .keys(object)
        .sort((a, b) => {
            function getV(s, side) {
                var offset = { 'Under': -1, null: 0, '+': 1 }[s.match(/Under|\+/)],
                    value = s.match(/\d+/g)[offset && side];
                return { value, offset };
            }
            
            var aa = getV(a, 1),
                bb = getV(b, 0);

            return aa.value - bb.value || aa.offset - bb.offset;
        }),
   newObject = Object.assign(...keys.map(k => ({ [k]: object[k] })));

console.log(newObject);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Please read the comments from OP in the question section

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal, what are you pointing to?

Comment: OP has a array of objects but it seems OP need sorting on first object of array. And your output is a object. I like your answer but the output does not match the OP's context

Comment: i think the op can take the first object without any problems. what kind of output does the op wants?

Comment: It is in the question itself, below `I want to sort the above array of object like`

Comment: i see no problem here, but anyway.

Comment: That's cool. Your answers are always great

Comment: There is no problem with the answer. Thank you very much @NinaScholz . It works like a charm. Some people are overcomplicating the simple things unnecessary.

Comment: "You could take the an offset" - Hey, even @NinaScholz can make typos, nobody is perfect after all :D

Comment: @Logar, you could edit, if you like (i did it.)

Comment: @NinaScholz Isn't there a rule that states that an edit should be more than x chars ? Last time I tried this kind of edit SO didn't let me

Comment: fair enough .. just add a joke as placeholder ... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can not do it directly. You have to change your structure. Something like this. I think the modified structure makes the same sense.

```js
let myObj = [{
  "60": 0.1413972485314015,
  "29": 0.0832178903621611,
  "49": 0.1033361204013377,
  "39": 0.0835906328864075,
  "18": 0.1326368677036551,
  "59": 0.1224973366151133
}]

let result = Object.keys(myObj[0]).sort((a, b) => a - b).map(val => ({
  [val]: myObj[0][val]
}));

console.log(result);
```